# error message not getting replace

Tags: catalog, messages, global-messages, error-message

On product page, I am doing add to cart with quantity more than the allowed in cart.
Page is getting refreshed and I am seeing the error message on the page.
After that I am adding single quantity and I am getting the success message but the error message is still there.

In console, I am seeing that error message is in cookieMessages ko template and success message is in messages ko template.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

How can I debug this issue?